# Configuration 'compile' in project ':app' is deprecated. Use 'implementation' instead

Tags: android, gradle

I already implemented, but still prompted me.

Android Studio 3.0

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
}


dependencies {
    implementation group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-simple', version: '1.7.20'
    implementation group: 'org.aspectj', name: 'aspectjrt', version: '1.8.9'
    implementation group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}
```

Comment: Could you provide the whole file and give your versions of gradle and ide?